# F# how to exit program when something went wrong

Tags: f#, f#-interactive

I'm new to `F#` and functional programming. I'm trying to write some simple scripts for processing files.

However sometimes early on in the program I might get an `exception`, because a file is not present or similar.

If I put everything in `option`s, my script gets cluttered with option handling in every subsequent method. Also I don't need to continue in the program, because it's already pointless.

How do I exit the program gracefully? I just want to end execution with a warning.

Using `exit` it crashes my `F# interactive` session in `Visual Studio Code`. Is there another way?

Comment: railway oriented programming? - or throwing exceptions

Comment: I had heard it before. Didn't really process it though. A look at http://de.slideshare.net/ScottWlaschin/railway-oriented-programming explains the concept quite well. I think I might build that into my script.

Answer (score 4):

You can raise an exception and either catch it in outmost layer of your program or just let it end the execution.

`failwith "Warning: my exception"` does the thing during development.

Answer (score 3):

This is a mix of F# and .NET exception handling in the end. For example:

```
open System
open System.IO

let openFile fName =
    try
        File.ReadAllLines fName
    with
        | :? System.IO.FileNotFoundException -> failwith "Oops"

let fName = @"c:\tmp\file1.csv"
openFile fName
let fName' = @"c:\tmp\nofile.csv"
openFile fName'
```

[F# Exception Handling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/exception-handling-%5Bfsharp%5D) and [Fun&Profit](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/exceptions/) are good sources for the details. And [ROP](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/rop/) was mentioned in the comment above.

And you can replace the `with` block: `| :? System.IO.FileNotFoundException -> [|"this"; "didn't";"work"|]`.

Comment: Perfect, this looks almost exactly like what I need!